# Set Debian Wheezy date to UTC

Tags: debian, date, utc

I'm not an expert in Linux servers, and I'd like to configure my server to use the UTC timezone, so there's no issue between the applications running on it. I don't really know how to do this. I `ntp ntpdate` (not sure whether it changes something).

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you do a:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

it should all work.
For more information check [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges).